# Can Webapp work exactly same as a desktop app using electron?

Tags: electron, desktop-application

if I build an angular app and feed run it using electron, will it work exactly like a web-application ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes it does work exactly like web-application.

Electron is chromium browser, and nodejs bundled together. Every app that is made for chrome would seamlessly work in electron, and would work exactly like a web app.

Comment: Even though adding webpack to electron is not the best idea. The most valid way is to use `electron-compile` instead. And just to follow the current tools of electron a good idea is to use https://electronforge.io/ for the whole bundle of useful tools. it comes with `electron-compile`, `electron-packer` and `electron-rebuild`